# Vertex AI notebook can't connect to PyTorch 2.0 Kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, jupyter, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

When I create a notebook instance with Google Cloud Vertex AI Workbench, I cannot use the PyTorch 2.0 kernel to run a script. It says 'connecting' for some time, and then says disconnected. However, I can use the ordinary Python kernel.

Edit: The issue seems to occur whenever I attach a GPU
[image]

Comment: Is this a User Managed Notebook? `PyTorch 2.0 (with Intel® MKL-DNN/MKL)`? I Was able to create a new UmN with Pytorch 2.0+GPU and use default Kernel, can you share more details and exact steps you are following. Thanks

Comment: @gogasca Im talking about managed notebooks

Comment: Im using Two T4 GPUs

Comment: I saw the same issue, thanks for reporting we will fix it and update this thread.

Comment: Sounds good. This is off topic but do you know what Quota name I should request to increase if I want to use GPUs on 'User-Managed Notebooks' or 'Instances'? I did it for 'Managed Notebooks' but I don't know how for the others, I am unable to attach GPUs to them.

Comment: We found an issue related to the CUDA version. (Pytorch is expecting a higher version cuda>=11.8 and OS has only 11.6) will be fixed in m118.

Comment: User Managed Notebooks+Workebench instances use your regular GCE quota (just as any VM)

Comment: Great, any ETA? Also what is m118

Comment: m118 is the version. https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/release-notes, we just release m117. Please monitor this link, will update ETA